# Max. Load Test Run Duration in Visual Studio Load Tests

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, load-testing

We are using Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 and Self Provisioned Rig for load generation.
Are there any limits for the test run duration?
Can the test run for 2 weeks continuous duration with load test agents in Self provisioned Rig in case of Soak Test scenario for an example?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it can run for two weeks. But I must caveat that by saying lots of data is stored in the computer's RAM as the test runs and lots more is written to the SQL database. I have no idea what the limits on their storage would be. Also running a test of that duration risks losing lots of data should something unexpected happen during the run.

See [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/SECURITY/en-US/977ec5e5-2548-4094-9e92-9cc5b36ae510/vs-load-test-unable-to-execute-a-672-hour-load-test?forum=vstest) where a 672 hour test failed with an integer overflow of a value holding milliseconds. Some quick sums suggest the integer would overflow at about 600 hours which is about 25 days.